# RadGrid merge header

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik

I have a RadGrid with four columns. Name, Contact No, [Edit button] and [Delete button]. I want to set single header "Action" for [Edit button] and [Delete button] columns. So that the gridview looks like below :

```
Name           Contact Number          Action
AAAA           9999999999          [Edit] [Delete]
BBBB           8888888888          [Edit] [Delete]
```

Is there any possible way to merge the header of two different columns? I want the same look as given above.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with `TemplateField`

```
<rad:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Action">
   <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:LinkButton ID="Edit" CommandName="Edit" runat="server" Text="[Edit]" />
     <asp:LinkButton ID="Delete" CommandName="Delete" runat="server" Text="[Delete]" />
   </ItemTemplate>
</rad:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: It was in same column before I have updated UI. As edit and delete buttons are image buttons, are creating UI and alignment issues in different browsers while insert/edit/delete. So that I have created two different columns for them.

Comment: what alignment? If it's squeezing you can give the templatefield enough width that won't allow the link to wrap or squeeze